# Nested Arrows with tkz-linknodes

Tags: align, arrows

I'm trying to replicate a notation used in Hauser's Introduction to Logic, using the tkz-linknodes package. The first obstacle was getting the arrows to appear on the left, not the right. But the main obstacle is getting them to nest properly. It seems like tkz link nodes was not designed to make them nest, just to make them overlap. I want 3 arrows. I've managed to get 2 working. Just need to link line 2 and line 7 now. Would expanding the margins of the align environment help? Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}
\tikzset{ArrowStyle/.style={>=latex,<-,text=black}}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style={pos=0.5,right}}
\title{Proof Scrap}
\author{Joe Fetus}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{NodesList}
\begin{align*}
& 1. \quad C \supset D & &\text{p} \  /\therefore A \supset [B \supset (C \supset D)]\\
& 2. \quad A &&\textbf{AP} \  /\therefore B \supset (C \supset D)  \\ 
\AddNode[2] & 3. \quad B &&\textbf{AP} \  /\therefore C \supset D \\
\AddNode & 4. \quad C &&\textbf{AP} \  /\therefore D  \\
&  5. \quad D && 1,4 \ \textbf{MP} \raise -1.2ex\hbox{\AddNode} \\ 
&  6. \quad C \supset D && 4–5 \ \textbf{CP} \raise -1.2ex\hbox{\AddNode[2]} \\ 
&  7. \quad B \supset (C \supset D) && 3–6 \  \textbf{CP} \\ 
&  8. \quad A \supset [B \supset (C \supset D)] && 2–7 \  \textbf{CP}
\end{align*}

\LinkNodes[margin=13cm]{}
\LinkNodes[margin=13.5cm]{}
\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: nested arrows]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}
\tikzset{ArrowStyle/.style={>=latex,<-,text=black}}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style={pos=0.5,right}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{NodesList}
    \begin{align*}
      & 1. \quad C \supset D & &\text{p} \  /\therefore A \supset [B \supset (C \supset D)]\\
      \AddNode[1] & 2. \quad A &&\textbf{AP} \  /\therefore B \supset (C \supset D)  \\
      \AddNode[2] & 3. \quad B && \textbf{AP} \  /\therefore C \supset D \\
      \AddNode[3] & 4. \quad C &&\textbf{AP} \  /\therefore D  \\
      &  5. \quad D && \text{1, 4 \textbf{MP}} \raise -1.2ex\hbox{\AddNode[3]} \\
      &  6. \quad C \supset D && \text{4--5 \textbf{CP}} \raise -1.2ex\hbox{\AddNode[2]} \\
      &  7. \quad B \supset (C \supset D) && \text{3--6 \textbf{CP}} \raise -1.2ex\hbox{\AddNode[1]} \\
      &  8. \quad A \supset [B \supset (C \supset D)] && \text{2--7  \textbf{CP}}
    \end{align*}

    \LinkNodes[margin=14cm]{}
    \LinkNodes[margin=13.5cm]{}
    \LinkNodes[margin=13cm]{}
  \end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

You need to add node groups in order, I think. So `1` must come before `2` and `2` before `3` when adding the first node for that group.

Note that `\textendash` is not proper in maths mode. I've put it within the scope of a `\text{}` to eliminate the warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see why my way didn't make sense now! And thanks for the tip about math mode grammar!

Comment: @Latexpet You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if it solves the problem.